# Django：model作成における継承について

Tags: python, django

Djangoのmodel作成で、ForeignKeyを指定して外部キーを参照したいのですが、
うまくいきません。

[ファイル構成概略]
App
|
|-base - models.py
|
|-dir1 - models.py
|-dir2 - models.py
(dirはこのほかにいくつかあります。)

[base/models.py]

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class BaseModel(models.Model):
    class Meta(object):
        abstract = True
        ordering = ('pk', )

    user_creating = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='user_creating_id',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    user_updating = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='user_updating_id',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

[dir1/models.py]

```
class ClinicRecords(BaseModel):
    """カルテ情報."""

    patient = models.Foreignkey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    height = models.IntegerField()
    (略)
```

[dir2/models.py]

```
class Photos(BaseModel):
    """写真情報."""

    clinic_record = models.ForeignKey(ClinicRecords, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    patient_status = models.IntegerField()
    head_image = models.URLField()
    (略)
```

上記のように
・dir1,dir2のmodels.pyの中で　BaseModelを継承する
・BaseModelではさらに、「Userモデル」を外部キーとしてリレーションしたい

この際、

```
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 
'（クラス名１）.user_updating' or '（クラス名２）.user_updating'.
　　　　（クラス名１）.user_updating: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for
 '（クラス名２）.user_updating' clashes with reverse query name for '（クラス名３）.user_updating'.
```

というエラーが出ます。

原因は明らかに
dir1やdir2のmodels.pyで継承している、親クラス：BaseModelの中でForeignKeyを使ってUserを呼び出しているからであることがわかっているのですが、この解決策がわかりませんでした。
こちらの解決策をご教示いただけますでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`%(class)s`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/2.0/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name-and-related-query-name)と[`%(app_label)s`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/2.0/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name-and-related-query-name)を使えばどうですか？

> ForeignKey もしくは ManyToManyField に対して related_name または related_query_name を使う場合、そのフィールドに対して 一意の 逆引き名およびクエリ名を常に定義しなければなりません。これは抽象基底クラスにおいて、フィールドが継承した子クラスそれぞれに含まれ、継承される毎にその属性値が完全に同じ値 (related_name と related_query_name も含む) となるため、通常問題となります。
>
> この問題に対処するため、抽象基底クラスにおいて related_name もしくは related_query_name を用いる場合(のみ)、その値の一部に '%(app_label)s' と '%(class)s' を含まなければなりません。

例えば、

```
user_updating = models.ForeignKey(
    User,
    related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_user_updating_id',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE
)
```

Comment: ご連絡遅くなり誠に申し訳ございません。
ご回答いただき誠にありがとうございます。
なぜエラーが出るのか、詳しく教えていただきありがとうございます。
ただ残念ながら教えていただいたやり方だと解決はできませんでした。
取り急ぎすべてのテーブルにそれぞれ追加したので問題は解決いたしました。
もし他にやり方などわかりましたらご教示いただけますと幸いです。ありがとうございました。